# Merging two figures with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have plotted the dataframe df as a stacked bar chart:

```
dft['Date'] = old['DATE'].dt.to_period('M')
df = dft.groupby(by=['Date', 'Size'])['Spend'].sum()  
stacked = df.unstack('Size').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

This stacked bar chart has bars sitting at every month.

I have another dataframe cir with quarterly data (every 3 months). I need this data as a bar covering all 3 months in the background of the main stacked bar chart. The following code plots the quarterly data on its own.

```
cir['date'] = ['3-15','4-15', '1-16', '2-16', '3-16', '4-16', '1-17', '2- 
17', '3-17', '4-17']
cir['value'] = [78.4, 13.5, 19.8, 19, 78.4, 123.2, 82.6, 86.4, 83.5, 12.2.4]
cir.plot.bar()
```

I would like to overlay these two plots (they have different y axis). I have tried using the subplots functionality but haven't really got anywhere.

Comment: Can you show your current plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more pseudo-code than actual code since you do not provide much information or the code you have written. Still, this can give you some hints on how to combine `pandas.DataFrame.plot` and `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` with different y axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

width = 1
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
value_x = np.arange(cir['value'])
ax1.bar(x, cir['value'], width = 3*width)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df.unstack('Size').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax2, secondary_y=True, width=width)

plt.show()
```

Note that the trick is to use `ax2 = ax1.twinx()` and plot your series on a different axis.

About `width`, I am not sure if this will work since I do not know what is your `x` axis. But this is just to give you an idea on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you this should be very helpful information. Note I have now added some more information about the axis.

Comment: To add the error just use `yerr=the_error` in `ax1.bar(x, cir['value'], width = 3*width, yerr=the_error)`.

Comment: you can play with `alpha=0.5` or something in between 0 and 1 in `ax1.bar(x, cir['value'], width = 3*width, alpha=0.5)` . Please consider accepting the answer if it helped and if you have new questions create new posts :)